Treeview for OPC UA Server in Python Tkinter using freeopcua
I'm writing a small client software for OPC UA and would like to display the content of the OPC UA Server as a Treeview like other Clients do it (opcua-client-gui, UaExpert, ...).
I struggle with:

searching for pulling the structure info from the server. I currently know the variables Display names and connect to them via server.via get_child([var_name]).
Finding the right Tkinter widget for this sort of display.
Implementing the server-structure into the display.

Help on any of the above steps is much appreciated.
